# Bokeh plot not showing

Tags: python, plot, visualization, bokeh

I'm trying to produce a Gantt chart style plot using stacked horizontal bars, however when I show() the plot, the page is blank, and the error I get in the js console is `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference`. I am able to view other Bokeh plots, such as the stacked vertical bars example in the Bokeh documentation.

This is the code I am using to create the plot

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Range1d

grouped=df.groupby('Org')
source=ColumnDataSource(grouped)

p=figure(title='Project Schedule', x_axis_type='datetime', y_range=grouped['Org'],
    x_range=Range1d(df.Start.min(),df.Finish.max()))



p.hbar_stack('Task', y='Org', height=0.9, source=source)

show(p)
```

And a sample of the data I use, in a pandas dataframe

```
   Org Task      Start     Finish
0   o1   t1 2019-11-19 2019-11-23
1   o1   t2 2019-11-23 2019-11-27
2   o1   t3 2019-11-27 2019-12-01
3   o1   t4 2019-12-02 2019-12-06
4   o2   t1 2019-11-20 2019-11-24
5   o2   t2 2019-11-24 2019-11-28
6   o2   t3 2019-12-01 2019-12-05
7   o2   t4 2019-12-05 2019-12-09
8   o3   t1 2019-11-20 2019-11-24
9   o3   t2 2019-11-24 2019-11-28
10  o3   t3 2019-12-01 2019-12-05
11  o3   t4 2019-12-05 2019-12-09
```

Comment: Did you check the javascript console in your browser? In the case of bokeh it often contains useful error messages.

Comment: The answer is probably in how you are ingesting the data, which you have not included. Are `Start` and `Finish` values actually datetime values (they need to be) or are they just plain strings?

Comment: `Start` and `Finish` are datetime values, they are converted with `pd.to_datetime()` after being read.

Comment: Any messages in the browser JS console? It's not really possible to speculate more without a complete reproducer to actually investigate.

Comment: `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference` is the error I have in the JS console. Outside of this code is logic to generate the dates and dataframe, the example dataframe or Tony's code below should make up for this. All the code related to bokeh is above

Answer (score 0):

You could do smth like this (Bokeh v1.3.0):

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Range1d
from bokeh.core.properties import value
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Org': ['o1', 'o1','o1','o1', 'o2','o2','o2','o2','o3','o3','o3','o3'],
                   'Task': ['t1', 't2','t3','t4', 't1', 't2','t3','t4','t1', 't2','t3','t4'],
                   'Start': pd.date_range('2019-02-24', periods=4*3, freq='D'),
                   'Finish': pd.date_range('2019-03-24', periods=4*3, freq='D')})
df['Diff'] = df['Finish'] - df['Start']

x = df['Task'].unique().tolist()
y = df['Org'].unique().tolist()

data1 = {'y': y}
data2 = {t: [df['Diff'][j + i % 4] for j in range(len(y))] for i, t in enumerate(x)}
data = {**data1, **data2}

p = figure(title='Project Schedule', y_range = y, x_axis_type='datetime')
p.hbar_stack(x, y='y', height=0.9, color=['red', 'blue', 'orange', 'green'], legend=[value(k) for k in x], source=data)

show(p)
```

But it is not working quite well, needs some more logic for calculating the time differences in ms, I guess...

[image]